# Golang multipart file form request

Tags: go, curl

I'm writing an API client against Mapbox, uploading a batch of svg images to a custom map. The api they provide for this is documented with an example cUrl call that works fine:

`curl -F images=@include/mapbox/sprites_dark/aubergine_selected.svg "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/<my_company>/<my_style_id>/sprite?access_token=$MAPBOX_API_KEY" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout`

When attemting to do the same from golang I quickly came across that the multiform library is very limited, and wrote some code to make the request as similar to the cUrl request mentioned above.

```golang
func createMultipartFormData(fileMap map[string]string) (bytes.Buffer, *multipart.Writer) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    var err error
    w := multipart.NewWriter(&b)
    var fw io.Writer
    for fileName, filePath := range fileMap {

        h := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
        h.Set("Content-Disposition",
            fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"`, "images", fileName))
        h.Set("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml")

        if fw, err = w.CreatePart(h); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error creating form File %v, %v", fileName, err)
            continue
        }

        fileContents, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
        fileContents = bytes.ReplaceAll(fileContents, []byte("\n"), []byte("."))

        blockSize := 64
        remainder := len(fileContents) % blockSize
        iterations := (len(fileContents) - remainder) / blockSize

        newBytes := []byte{}
        for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
            start := i * blockSize
            end := i*blockSize + blockSize
            newBytes = append(newBytes, fileContents[start:end]...)
            newBytes = append(newBytes, []byte("\n")...)
        }

        if remainder > 0 {
            newBytes = append(newBytes, fileContents[iterations*blockSize:]...)
            newBytes = append(newBytes, []byte("\n")...)
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error reading svg file: %v: %v", filePath, err)
            continue
        }

        _, err = fw.Write(newBytes)

        if err != nil {
            log.Debugf("Could not write file to multipart: %v, %v", fileName, err)
            continue
        }
    }

    w.Close()

    return b, w
}
```

Along with setting the headers in the actual request:

```golang
    bytes, formWriter := createMultipartFormData(filesMap)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("Post", fmt.Sprintf("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/%v/%v/sprite?access_token=%v", "my_company", styleID, os.Getenv("MAPBOX_API_KEY")), &bytes)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "curl/7.64.1")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprintf("%v", len(bytes.Bytes())))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", formWriter.FormDataContentType())

    byts, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)
    fmt.Println(string(byts))

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

Even want as far to limit the line length and replicate the encoding used by cUrl but so far no luck. Does anyone with experience know why this works from cUrl but not golang?

Comment: Assorted points: 1) multipart/form library in Go covers 100% of possible use cases; it merely implements the spec. I have no idea why you find it limited. 2) The dance you're doing with the file's data is most probably not what you want. Does that "mapbox" thing has a real API doc to look at (as opposed to a curl invocation example, which is not documentation).

Comment: I'm pretty new to go, but yes maybe not limited, low level is more like it. The FormFile method for example does not allow for custom content types of the enclosed files. The Mapbox docs are limited, but they provide a working cUrl example that I dumped to stdout, then I did the same for golang to compare the raw requests going out.

Comment: The output from --trace-ascii is a human readable representation of what curl writes to the network. The output  is not the  actual data written to the network.   To replicate the curl command in Go, create the part, write the data as is to the part and close the writer. It's three lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I admit that all the parts of the "puzzle" to solve your task can be found on the 'net in abundance, there are two problems with this:

- They quite often miss certain interesting details.
- Sometimes, they give outright incorrect advice.

So, here's a working solution.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "mime"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "net/textproto"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    const (
        dst   = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/AcmeInc/Style_001/sprite"
        fname = "path/to/a/sprite/image.svg"
        token = "an_invalid_token"
    )

    err := post(dst, fname, token)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func post(dst, fname, token string) error {
    u, err := url.Parse(dst)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to parse destination url: %w", err)
    }

    form, err := makeRequestBody(fname)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to prepare request body: %w", err)
    }

    q := u.Query()
    q.Set("access_token", token)
    u.RawQuery = q.Encode()

    hdr := make(http.Header)
    hdr.Set("Content-Type", form.contentType)
    req := http.Request{
        Method:        "POST",
        URL:           u,
        Header:        hdr,
        Body:          ioutil.NopCloser(form.body),
        ContentLength: int64(form.contentLen),
    }

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(&req)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to perform http request: %w", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    _, _ = io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body)

    return nil
}

type form struct {
    body        *bytes.Buffer
    contentType string
    contentLen  int
}

func makeRequestBody(fname string) (form, error) {
    ct, err := getImageContentType(fname)
    if err != nil {
        return form{}, fmt.Errorf(
            `failed to get content type for image file "%s": %w`,
            fname, err)
    }

    fd, err := os.Open(fname)
    if err != nil {
        return form{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to open file to upload: %w", err)
    }
    defer fd.Close()

    stat, err := fd.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return form{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to query file info: %w", err)
    }

    hdr := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    cd := mime.FormatMediaType("form-data", map[string]string{
        "name":     "images",
        "filename": fname,
    })
    hdr.Set("Content-Disposition", cd)
    hdr.Set("Contnt-Type", ct)
    hdr.Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(stat.Size(), 10))

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    mw := multipart.NewWriter(&buf)

    part, err := mw.CreatePart(hdr)
    if err != nil {
        return form{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to create new form part: %w", err)
    }

    n, err := io.Copy(part, fd)
    if err != nil {
        return form{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to write form part: %w", err)
    }

    if int64(n) != stat.Size() {
        return form{}, fmt.Errorf("file size changed while writing: %s", fd.Name())
    }

    err = mw.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return form{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to prepare form: %w", err)
    }

    return form{
        body:        &buf,
        contentType: mw.FormDataContentType(),
        contentLen:  buf.Len(),
    }, nil
}

var imageContentTypes = map[string]string{
    "png":  "image/png",
    "jpg":  "image/jpeg",
    "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
    "svg":  "image/svg+xml",
}

func getImageContentType(fname string) (string, error) {
    ext := filepath.Ext(fname)
    if ext == "" {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("file name has no extension: %s", fname)
    }

    ext = strings.ToLower(ext[1:])
    ct, found := imageContentTypes[ext]
    if !found {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("unknown file name extension: %s", ext)
    }

    return ct, nil
}
```

Some random notes on implementation to help you understands the concepts:

- To construct the request's payload (body), we use a `bytes.Buffer` instance.
  It has a nice property in that a pointer to it (`*bytes.Buffer`) implements both `io.Writer` and `io.Reader` and hence can be easily composed with other parts of the Go stdlib which deal with I/O.
- When preparing a multipart form for sending, we do not slurp the whole file's contents into memory but instead "pipe" them right into the "mutipart form writer".
- We have a lookup table which maps the extension of a file name to submit to its MIME type; I have no idea whether this is needed by the API or not; if it's not really required, the part of the code which prepares a form's field containing a file could be simplified a lot, but cURL send it, so do we.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It looks like the part constructing the actual request was the difference here, not totally sure though... But this confirms my initial feeling that the multiform package is somewhat limited. It's really nice to see this thoroughly defensive coding as well, and I need to stop using ioutil for reading files :) Thanks for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: @arnaldur, two notes: 1) if you mean `form/multipart` is limited by not having a way to read files by names or map "known" filename extensions to their mime types, that's not the package being limited, that's a sign of it being correctly engineered as it has clearly delimted API. 2) defensive coding is a bit different thing; this is just sensible error handling—where you wrap the error in contexts as it bubbles up to the caller ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be curious, What is this for?

```
        fileContents = bytes.ReplaceAll(fileContents, []byte("\n"), []byte("."))

        blockSize := 64
        remainder := len(fileContents) % blockSize
        iterations := (len(fileContents) - remainder) / blockSize

        newBytes := []byte{}
        for i := 0; i < iterations; i++ {
            start := i * blockSize
            end := i*blockSize + blockSize
            newBytes = append(newBytes, fileContents[start:end]...)
            newBytes = append(newBytes, []byte("\n")...)
        }

        if remainder > 0 {
            newBytes = append(newBytes, fileContents[iterations*blockSize:]...)
            newBytes = append(newBytes, []byte("\n")...)
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error reading svg file: %v: %v", filePath, err)
            continue
        }
```

Reading a entire file into memory is rarely a good idea (`ioutil.ReadFile`).

As @muffin-top says, how about those three lines of code?

```
    for fileName, filePath := range fileMap {

        // h := ...

        fw, _ := w.CreatePart(h) // TODO: handle error

        f, _ := os.Open(filePath) // TODO: handle error

        io.Copy(fw, f) // TODO: handle error

        f.Close() // TODO: handle error
    }
```

Comment: I started with the basic implementation like you suggest... then I was going far into the rabbit hole, chasing every detail of cUrl's output like it was scripture. And that produced the line limiting code you asked about. Good tip about ioutil.ReadFile, becoming more fluent with readers and writers going throught this issue