# How to set the Content-Type differently for each key value when requesting POST with multipart/form-data in Golang

Tags: http, go, request, postman

When requesting POST with multipart/form-data using Golang, is there a way to send the request by setting the content-type differently for each key? For example, one key will send a file, and one key will send data in json format in application/json type. It was possible with postman, but I couldn't find a way to do it with Golang. If you know, please share it with me. Thank you. :)

Below is the cURL of the successful request value in postman.

```
curl --location --request POST '{API_URL}' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID={}' \
--form 'images=@"{dsfsdfs.png}"' \
--form 'request="{ \"id\": \"yoon\", \"memberName\": \"yoon\"}";type=application/json'
```

And when I tried several times in Golang, I got an error requesting the content type 'application/octet-stream'.

Comment: When [creating the part](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Writer.CreatePart),  set the content type in the part header.

Comment: *"And when I tried several times in Golang, "* - it is unclear what you actually did, so it is impossible to point out what you did wrong and how to improve your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang multipart file form request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636454/golang-multipart-file-form-request)